# Performing an action if two conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is based on some help I received earlier but I need two conditions to be met and can only get one to work. I also need the action to occur if the third row of each column in the loop is equal to cell A34. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Long
    Dim cell As Range, c As Range, bEmpty As Boolean
    
    Set ws = Worksheets("January")
         For Each c In Range("B5:AF20").Cells
            If c.Value2 = ws.Range("A36").Value2 Then
   
            For r = 5 To 20
            c.Offset(0, -2) = "R"
                
            Next
            If bEmpty Then c.Offset(40) = "No"
            
        End If
    Next
    
    MsgBox "Done"
    
       
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use an `And` in your `If` statement: `If c.Value2 = ws.Range("A36").Value2 And c.Offset(40) = "No" Then`

Comment: The value in the 3rd row will be `.Cells(3,c.column).value2`. The code in the `For r` loop does not contain `r` which makes no sense.